# Set Can not setup between 2 QHBoxLayout on 1 QVBoxLayout

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qvboxlayout

Currently, I met the problem is when I run it only shows QHVerticalRight, maybeQHVeritcalLeft was overwritten by QHVerticalRight.

Here is the sample code for that:
`

```
class DataEntryForm(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layoutVerLeft = QVBoxLayout()
        self.items = 0
        self.flag = 0
        self._data = {}
        self.lstClear = ['Xóa tất cả', 'Lựa chọn dòng']

        self.table          = QTableWidget()
        self.labelImage     = QLabel()
        self.layoutVer      = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layoutHLeft    = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layoutHRight   = QVBoxLayout()

        self.lineEditName   = QLineEdit()
        self.lineEditBirth  = QDateEdit()
        self.lineEditPos    = QLineEdit()
        self.lineEditClub   = QLineEdit()
        self.lineEditNumber = QLineEdit()
        self.comboBoxClear  = QComboBox()

        self.buttonAdd      = QPushButton('Thêm')
        self.buttonQuit     = QPushButton('Thoát')
        self.buttonPlot     = QPushButton('Vẽ biểu đồ')
        self.buttonEdit     = QPushButton('Bật/Tắt Chỉnh Sửa')
        self.buttonSaveImg  = QPushButton('Lưu Biểu Đồ')
        self.buttonSaveFile = QPushButton('Lưu Database')
        self.buttonClear    = QPushButton('Xóa')


        # Layout Horizontal Left
        self.layoutHorizonLeft()
        # Layout Horizontal Right
        self.layoutHorizonRight()

        self.layoutVer.addLayout(self.layoutHLeft)
        self.layoutVer.addLayout(self.layoutHRight)
        self.fill_table()

    def layoutHorizonLeft(self):
        # Define Widget as you want
        self.table.setColumnCount(5)
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(('Họ và Tên', 'Ngày Sinh', 'Vị Trí', 'Câu Lạc Bộ', 'Số Áo'))
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
        # Define Vertical Box
        layoutVerLeft = QVBoxLayout()
        # Image add Widget
        layoutVerLeft.addWidget(self.labelImage, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.labelImage.setPixmap(QPixmap('football-manager-2021.jpg'))
        # Table add Widget
        layoutVerLeft.addWidget(self.table)
        self.table.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        # Add Layout
        self.layoutHLeft.addLayout(layoutVerLeft)
        # Set Layout
        self.setLayout(self.layoutHLeft)

    def layoutHorizonRight(self):
        # Define Verical Box
        layoutVerRight = QVBoxLayout()

        # Tạo combo box clear
        self.comboBoxClear.addItems(self.lstClear)
        self.comboBoxClear.setEditable(True)
        self.comboBoxClear.setFixedHeight(25)

        lineEditComboClear = self.comboBoxClear.lineEdit()
        lineEditComboClear.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        lineEditComboClear.setReadOnly(True)

        # Cài đặt độ cao của các button
        # self.buttonAdd.setFixedHeight(25)
        # self.buttonQuit.setFixedHeight(25)
        # self.buttonPlot.setFixedHeight(25)
        # self.buttonEdit.setFixedHeight(25)
        # self.buttonSaveImg.setFixedHeight(25)
        # self.buttonSaveFile.setFixedHeight(25)
        # self.buttonClear.setFixedHeight(25)

        # Set button Thêm = False, để user nhập đầy đủ thông tin mới cho nhấn vào
        self.buttonAdd.setEnabled(False)

        # Khoảng cách giữa các khung nhập
        layoutVerRight.setSpacing(5)

        # Khung nhập thông tin
        # Họ Tên
        layoutVerRight.addWidget(QLabel('Họ và Tên'))
        layoutVerRight.addWidget(self.lineEditName)
        self.lineEditName.setMaxLength(25)
        # Năm Sinh
        layoutVerRight.addWidget(QLabel('Năm Sinh'))
        layoutVerRight.addWidget(self.lineEditBirth)
        self.lineEditBirth.setDisplayFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
        self.lineEditBirth.setCalendarPopup(True)
        self.lineEditBirth.setMinimumDate(QDate(1900, 1, 1))
        self.lineEditBirth.setMaximumDate(QDate(2100, 1, 1))
        self.lineEditBirth.setDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime())
        # Vị Trí
        layoutVerRight.addWidget(QLabel('Vị Trí'))
        layoutVerRight.addWidget(self.lineEditPos)
        self.lineEditPos.setMaxLength(20)
        # Câu Lạc Bộ
        layoutVerRight.addWidget(QLabel('Câu Lạc Bộ'))
        layoutVerRight.addWidget(self.lineEditClub)
        self.lineEditClub.setMaxLength(25)
        # Số áo
        layoutVerRight.addWidget(QLabel('Số Áo Thi Đấu'))
        layoutVerRight.addWidget(self.lineEditNumber)
        self.lineEditNumber.setValidator(QIntValidator())
        self.lineEditNumber.setMaxLength(2)

        # Nút nhấn lựa chọn chức năng
        layoutRight_AddEdit = QHBoxLayout()
        layoutRight_AddEdit.addWidget(self.buttonAdd)
        layoutRight_AddEdit.addWidget(self.buttonEdit)
        layoutRight_Clear = QHBoxLayout()
        layoutRight_Clear.addWidget(self.comboBoxClear)
        layoutRight_Clear.addWidget(self.buttonClear)
        layoutRight_PlotQuit = QHBoxLayout()
        layoutRight_PlotQuit.addWidget(self.buttonPlot)
        layoutRight_PlotQuit.addWidget(self.buttonQuit)
        layoutRight_Save = QHBoxLayout()
        layoutRight_Save.addWidget(self.buttonSaveImg)
        layoutRight_Save.addWidget(self.buttonSaveFile)

        # Set layout theo thứ tự từ trên xuống
        layoutVerRight.addLayout(layoutRight_AddEdit)
        layoutVerRight.addLayout(layoutRight_Clear)
        layoutVerRight.addLayout(layoutRight_Save)
        layoutVerRight.addLayout(layoutRight_PlotQuit)

        # chart widget
        chartView = QChartView()
        chartView.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        layoutVerRight.addWidget(chartView)

        # Add Layout
        self.layoutHRight.addLayout(layoutVerRight)
        # Set Layout
        self.setLayout(self.layoutHRight)

        self.buttonQuit.clicked.connect(self.quit_message)
        self.buttonPlot.clicked.connect(self.graph_chart)
        self.buttonAdd.clicked.connect(self.add_entry)
        self.buttonEdit.clicked.connect(self.edit_database)
        self.buttonSaveImg.clicked.connect(self.export_img)
        self.buttonSaveFile.clicked.connect(self.export_db_file)
        self.buttonClear.clicked.connect(self.comboBox_Clear)

        self.lineEditName.textChanged[str].connect(self.check_disable)
        self.lineEditPos.textChanged[str].connect(self.check_disable)
        self.lineEditClub.textChanged[str].connect(self.check_disable)
        self.lineEditNumber.textChanged.connect(self.check_disable)
```

`

This image describe the position for layoutHorizonLeft and layoutHorizonRight define:
[image: This image describe the position for layoutHorizonLeft and layoutHorizonRight define]

Comment: Please, for future reference, when you are going to provide examples, ensure that their code is *both* [minimal *and* reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example): a lot of your code is completely useless for your question, and many lines have to be commented out (since they refer to functions that don't exist) in order to make it work. Always try your code on a separate file before submitting it for a question.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to set the two vertical layouts as main layouts, and you're not setting the *actual* layout you need, the horizontal one.

Remove both `setLayout()` at the end of `layoutHorizonLeft` and `layoutHorizonRight`, and add the following line at the end of the `__init__`.

```py
        self.setLayout(self.layoutVer)
```

Or, alternatively, just create that layout with the widget in the constructor:

```py
        self.layoutVer = QHBoxLayout(self)
```

Consider that you're adding an unnecessary level of layouts:

- `layoutVerLeft` is useless, as you can add all widgets to `self.layoutHLeft`;
- the same for `layoutVerRight`, since you can add all those widgets to `self.layoutHRight`;

<sup>Note: don't confuse horizontal and vertical layouts and their namings.</sup>

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I am misunderstanding which one to be a main and give "self" into the expected Layout.

Comment: @HòaNguyễnLêMinh you're welcome. Remember that if an answer solves your question, you should mark it as accepted by clicking on the gray tick mark on its left. Also, always look at the output of the programs you run (and remember that you should also try to launch them in a terminal or prompt, as IDEs sometimes miss the full traceback or even hide some errors): in your case, you would have seen an alert from Qt notifying you that you were trying to set a layout on a widget that already had one set for it.

Comment: Hi I can not set the config for height of button. Please help me check this problem.
self.buttonAdd.setFixedHeight(25)
==> This button is only at default setting

Comment: @michaelkenshijpv97 can you please try to clarify what you mean? It could be useful if you could add a link to a screenshot of what you're getting.

Comment: Hi, sorry for my late reply . I resolved my problem and idea for this. Many thanks.

Comment: @michaelkenshijpv97 as said, if the question is solved by my answer, you should mark it as accepted. If it's not, you should clarify what the problem is so that we can find a way to actually solve it. Remember that StackOverflow is a community effort, and answers are helpful not only to those who ask them, but to anybody else too.